# In C++, which is better i>-1 or i>=0

Tags: c++, optimization, premature-optimization

This might be a silly question to ask, but this kind of optimization is sometimes boost performance of your application.
Here I am asking specifically for C++, because the way C++ compile code is a lot different that c# or Java.

The question is which one performs better, if variable i is int.

1. `i > -1`
2. `i >= 0`

I am looking for performance in terms of  memory block or registers required and  CPU cycles required for both conditions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The generated assembly code is nearly same. I don't think there is any difference here.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135518/is-faster-than) out.

Comment: Micro-Optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Depends a lot on the instruction set.  Some have special instructions for test against zero.

Comment: Check this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520830/x-1-vs-x-0-is-there-a-performance-difference

Comment: that depends if `i` is an integer or not!

Comment: i is integer, indeed.

Comment: The compiler will use whichever one is faster anyway so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In assembly language, both are on the same structure:

1. `i > -1`

   ```
   cmp   [register with i value],-1
   jg    [somewhere]
   ```
2. `i >= 0`

   ```
   cmp   [register with i value],0
   jge   [somewhere]
   ```

According to [used jump flags](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html), the instruction `jg` make two flags comparaisons (ZF = 0 and SF = OF) but `jge` does only one (SF = OF).

So I'm tempted to say that both use almost same registers and CPU cycles, with maybe a very little quicker comparaison for `i >= 0`.

Comment: Even 2 flag comparisons instead of one would take the same number of cycles, no?

Comment: @RSinohara I don't think so. Take the same sample in programming code: what is the slower between `if (something)` and `if (something && something_else)` ?

Comment: Loading the immediate value -1 could be more expensive or require more bytes. Unclear, whether the JIT optimized one form to the other.

Comment: @usr No. Take a look: http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf
Every jcc (jump if condition) are grouped together in the Latency/Throughput table in appendix C.

Comment: @RSinohara I'm talking about loading the constant -1, not about the jump. Clearly, all jumps and comparisons have the same cost (a tiny one).

Comment: Both -1 and 0 will take a byte in machine code. The byte is read in full from memory, taking the very same time (same instruction). It would take longer if you compared to someting >255

Answer (score 2):

Well, according to logic > operation may be "cheaper" than >=, but I guess you are compiling with Optimization option enabled, so probably the compiler do whatever he wants to optimize your code, so I would say that doesn't matter, even if one is really faster, probably the compiler change it to the best option

Answer (score 0):

When writing a for loop it could be beneficial to convert it from `for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)` to `for (i = 1000; i > 0; i--)` because on some architectures the compiler can skip the compare instruction as a flag will be set when i reaches 0. On modern architectures I'm not sure it matters.