# When possible, should a programmer always use < rather than <=?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Consider the two for-loop declarations:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 70; ++i)
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 69; ++i)
```

I'm assuming the second one is going to make 139 total comparisons rather than 69. Is my assumption correct? I'm not an electrical engineer, so I don't know how an ALU actually works, whether it does a "less than or equals" thingamabob in one fell swoop or what.

Can you give an example of when using a `<=` is justified?

By the way, I'm trying to become a "hardcore" programmer like you guys are.

Comment: The first makes more sense to read usually, as the loop will run 70 times (assuming you don't use break or change `i` inside the loop).

Comment: `<` and `<=` are consuming equal amount of CPU ticks

Comment: Also, why would the second make 139 comparisons?

Comment: Both will compile to exactly the same number of instructions. On x86, the relevant instructions are `JE` and `JAE` (jump if above or equal).

Comment: "<" will save one keystroke and is quicker to read for humans.

Comment: You use the operator that's appropriate... that's why they both exist

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is < faster than <=?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135518/is-faster-than)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no right or wrong answer here.

Different loops will have different requirements. Sometimes you will use `<` and sometimes you  will use `<=`. Other times you will use `>`!

Oh god, the possibilities! You could use `&&` or `||` or ...

Sometimes you won't even use an operator at all! You could use the value of a variable!

Or the return value of a function!

Or... a boolean!

---

Also, please look into [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Given the following logical expression

```
9 < 10 || 9 == 10
```

only 1 comparison will be made because the first half is true.

I would trust that `<=` is optimized accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

The relevant thing is not whether using '<'  or '<=', that's irrelevant.

The important thing is whether `70` or `69` is the important thing in your program.

That is, if your array has `70` elements, then the most logical course of action is to write `70`, and use the according operand.

For example, in languages with 1-based arrays you will write:

```
for i = 1, i <= 70
```

but in 0-based arrays:

```
for i = 0, i < 70
```

Answer (score 0):

No. The first and second loop makes same number of loops, which is 70.

There is also no comparison made. A `for-loop` structure like what you have typed only makes a line or a block of code to repeat itself.

If you want comparison, you need to use an `if` statement.

when to use `<` and `<=` is all personal coding preference. So long as it gives you the same outcome, you are safe to use either one.

Of course there may might certain case where it will be better to use one over the other. But those are only specific cases.

**Edit:** If a glass is half empty, will you say it is half-empty or half-full? Your answer will probably be "Both seems the same to me.". Similar for choosing `<` and `<=`. You are free to use whichever you are comfortable with. No fixed rule for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `<=` will make two comparisons and `<` just one. The compiler doesn't usually interpret this operators literally and may internally change `<=`  to `<`.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the other answer, in your case, `for (int i = 0; i < 70; ++i)` is more conventional because once used to it, it's easy to see at first sight that we'll have 70 iterations (from 0 to 69 included).