# '<=' versus '<' in for loop

Tags: c#, loops

Just having a question that any of the following loop is better or both are same

option 1

```
for(i=0; i<=3; i++)
{
    //Do something
}
```

option 2

```
for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: They are the same. They will both iterate from 0-3.

Comment: It is a matter of personal choice.

Comment: Related.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135518/is-faster-than

Comment: As long as you want to iterate from 0 to 3, they both are the same. It is a matter of personal style. As myself, I prefer the later.

Comment: they both come down to one machine instruction `leq` or `lt`

Comment: I'd like to point out that option 2 is common practice, unless option 1 suits better (The upper bound is most likely a variable and you want to use it as is, do not write `i <= length - 1`)

Comment: @MarkO - common practice in your work place maybe, I always use option one as I find it clearer as to what the exact end point of the loop is.

Comment: I agree with MarkO here, `for(iterationCursor=0;iterationCursor<collectionLength;iterationCursor++)` reads more natural than `for(iterationCursor=0;iterationCursor<=collectionLength-1;iterationCursor++)`

Answer (score 1):

Those two loops are identical in execution. The second part of the for expression is the comparison to be used to determine continuation of the loop; since you are starting from zero and incrementing by one, these two expressions will always yield the same results.