# Best way x <= n or x < n+1?

Tags: php, syntax

I was asking to myself what was the best way to compare between :

```
$count < 3
```

and

```
$count <= 2
```

or if it was exactly the same, no matter what.
I'm talking in PHP but I guess it's the same for a lot of language.

Comment: I dont think it is going to make any difference!

Comment: If $count is an integer, the result will be the same, but in term of performances, I don't know.

Comment: Those two should be equivalent, I think. `$count < $length` and `$count <= $length - 1` should not (as you have an extra subtraction). The difference is tiny and probably not worth obsessing over.

Comment: In C++ there would be essentially no difference between the two, q.v. [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135518/is-faster-than).  PHP is interpreted, so you would have to know how the interpreted code would handle it, but it's likely analogous to most assemblers.

Comment: I would use the one that makes most sense when reading the code. If I want an if-loop for values lower than 50, I want to see 50 in my code for easy reference, not 51.

Comment: I prefer `x <= n` than `x < n+1` because php should do nothing to compare condition, in case `x < n+1`  php should calculate result each time...

Comment: I was just using _n+1_ in order not to use a specific number, but my exemple is what I really mean.
@RST comment makes sense, thanks !