# > vs. >= in bubble sort causes significant performance difference

Tags: java, c++, performance, optimization

I just stumbled upon something. At first I thought it might be a case of branch misprediction like it is [in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array), but I cannot explain why branch misprediction should cause this behaviour.

I implemented two versions of Bubble Sort in Java and did some performance testing:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class BubbleSortAnnomaly {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        final int ARRAY_SIZE = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        final int LIMIT = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        final int RUNS = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

        int[] a = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
        int[] b = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int run = 0; RUNS > run; ++run) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
                a[i] = r.nextInt(LIMIT);
                b[i] = a[i];
            }

            System.out.print("Sorting with sortA: ");
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            int swaps = bubbleSortA(a);

            System.out.println(  (System.nanoTime() - start) + " ns. "
                               + "It used " + swaps + " swaps.");

            System.out.print("Sorting with sortB: ");
            start = System.nanoTime();
            swaps = bubbleSortB(b);

            System.out.println(  (System.nanoTime() - start) + " ns. "
                               + "It used " + swaps + " swaps.");
        }
    }

    public static int bubbleSortA(int[] a) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
                if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
                    swap(a, j, j + 1);
                    ++counter;
                }
            }
        }
        return (counter);
    }

    public static int bubbleSortB(int[] a) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
                if (a[j] >= a[j + 1]) {
                    swap(a, j, j + 1);
                    ++counter;
                }
            }
        }
        return (counter);
    }

    private static void swap(int[] a, int j, int i) {
        int h = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = h;
    }
}
```

As we can see, the only difference between those two sorting methods is the `>` vs. `>=`. When running the program with `java BubbleSortAnnomaly 50000 10 10`, one would obviously expect that `sortB` is slower than `sortA` because it has to execute more `swap(...)`s. But I got the following (or similar) output on three different machines:

```
Sorting with sortA: 4.214 seconds. It used  564960211 swaps.
Sorting with sortB: 2.278 seconds. It used 1249750569 swaps.
Sorting with sortA: 4.199 seconds. It used  563355818 swaps.
Sorting with sortB: 2.254 seconds. It used 1249750348 swaps.
Sorting with sortA: 4.189 seconds. It used  560825110 swaps.
Sorting with sortB: 2.264 seconds. It used 1249749572 swaps.
Sorting with sortA: 4.17  seconds. It used  561924561 swaps.
Sorting with sortB: 2.256 seconds. It used 1249749766 swaps.
Sorting with sortA: 4.198 seconds. It used  562613693 swaps.
Sorting with sortB: 2.266 seconds. It used 1249749880 swaps.
Sorting with sortA: 4.19  seconds. It used  561658723 swaps.
Sorting with sortB: 2.281 seconds. It used 1249751070 swaps.
Sorting with sortA: 4.193 seconds. It used  564986461 swaps.
Sorting with sortB: 2.266 seconds. It used 1249749681 swaps.
Sorting with sortA: 4.203 seconds. It used  562526980 swaps.
Sorting with sortB: 2.27  seconds. It used 1249749609 swaps.
Sorting with sortA: 4.176 seconds. It used  561070571 swaps.
Sorting with sortB: 2.241 seconds. It used 1249749831 swaps.
Sorting with sortA: 4.191 seconds. It used  559883210 swaps.
Sorting with sortB: 2.257 seconds. It used 1249749371 swaps.
```

When I set the parameter for `LIMIT` to, e.g., `50000` (`java BubbleSortAnnomaly 50000 50000 10`), I get the expected results:

```
Sorting with sortA: 3.983 seconds. It used  625941897 swaps.
Sorting with sortB: 4.658 seconds. It used  789391382 swaps.
```

I ported the program to C++ to determine whether this problem is Java-specific. Here is the C++ code.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include <omp.h>

#ifndef ARRAY_SIZE
#define ARRAY_SIZE 50000
#endif

#ifndef LIMIT
#define LIMIT 10
#endif

#ifndef RUNS
#define RUNS 10
#endif

void swap(int * a, int i, int j)
{
    int h = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = h;
}

int bubbleSortA(int * a)
{
    const int LAST = ARRAY_SIZE - 1;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = LAST; 0 < i; --i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        {
            int next = j + 1;
            if (a[j] > a[next])
            {
                swap(a, j, next);
                ++counter;
            }
        }
    }
    return (counter);
}

int bubbleSortB(int * a)
{
    const int LAST = ARRAY_SIZE - 1;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = LAST; 0 < i; --i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        {
            int next = j + 1;
            if (a[j] >= a[next])
            {
                swap(a, j, next);
                ++counter;
            }
        }
    }
    return (counter);
}

int main()
{
    int * a = (int *) malloc(ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(int));
    int * b = (int *) malloc(ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(int));

    for (int run = 0; RUNS > run; ++run)
    {
        for (int idx = 0; ARRAY_SIZE > idx; ++idx)
        {
            a[idx] = std::rand() % LIMIT;
            b[idx] = a[idx];
        }

        std::cout << "Sorting with sortA: ";
        double start = omp_get_wtime();
        int swaps = bubbleSortA(a);

        std::cout << (omp_get_wtime() - start) << " seconds. It used " << swaps
                  << " swaps." << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Sorting with sortB: ";
        start = omp_get_wtime();
        swaps = bubbleSortB(b);

        std::cout << (omp_get_wtime() - start) << " seconds. It used " << swaps
                  << " swaps." << std::endl;
    }

    free(a);
    free(b);

    return (0);
}
```

This program shows the same behaviour. Can someone explain what exactly is going on here?

Executing `sortB` first and then `sortA` does not change the results.

Comment: How did you measure the time? If you measure the time only for one case, the timing will strongly depend on the random sequences and `>` vs `>=` will have only minor impact. To get really meaningful numbers for times you have to measure many different sequences and average

Comment: @tobi303 look at the code. You can run it in a loop via the 3rd runtime parameter (Java) or `-DRUNS=XXX` (C++, compiler directive). And the results are reproducible.

Comment: would be interesting to count the number of swaps in both cases to see how this relates to the runtime. I mean in case A is slower, this is definitely not due to the number of swaps, so maybe in case A is faster, the reason is also not simply the number of swaps but some more subtle effects

Comment: @Turing85: But did you rerun the test?

Comment: It would also be interesting to see if the results hold when calling `bubbleSortB()` first and then `bubbleSortA()`. With Java I often suspect memory allocation and gc causes unexpected results. Although getting the same results in C++ would suggest something more general is going on here.

Comment: @user2357112 yes. As I said: three different machines, same exact result.

Comment: You might also want to add a `System.gc()` prior to each bubble sort method call to help equalize the playing field between the tests. Also, allocate plenty of heap (`-xms256m -xmx256m`) and make sure the process isn't being swapped.

Comment: @KevinCondon Tested this as well. Changing the order around (first `sortB`, then `sortA`) did not change the results.

Comment: @tobi303 added the number of swaps.

Comment: @Turing85 One crude way to test if this is related to branch misprediction without getting into a profiler is to just ensure that that all of your elements are unique instead of completely random. For the C++ side, you can use std::sort and std::unique.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think it may indeed be due to branch prediction. If you count the number of swaps compared to the number of inner sort iterations you find:

**Limit = 10**

- A = 560M swaps / 1250M loops
- B = 1250M swaps / 1250M loops (0.02% less swaps than loops)

**Limit = 50000**

- A = 627M swaps / 1250M loops
- B = 850M swaps / 1250M loops

So in the `Limit == 10` case the swap is performed 99.98% of the time in the B sort which is obviously favourable for the branch predictor. In the `Limit == 50000` case the swap is only hit randomly 68% so the branch predictor is less beneficial.

Comment: Your argument seems sensible. Is there any way to test your hypothesis?

Comment: Quick answer is to control the input arrays to something such that the sorts for A/B do the same swaps in the same order (at least roughly). Exactly how to do this I don't know. You could also look at how random the swap order is "somehow" and see if that correlates to the sort times.

Comment: For cases where `LIMIT >= ARRAY_SIZE` you can do a test case where the array is composed of unique numbers. For example, in the case of `a[i] = ARRAY_SIZE - i` you get a swap on every loop and identical times for the A/B sorts.

Comment: @Turing85, note that my answer does in fact explain, _why_ is this difference in number of swaps.

Comment: @Petr why there is a larger number of swaps was obvious for me. I just was not able to correlate this fact with the branch misprediction. And the chosen answer gave (in my sight) the best explanation with the best argumentation.

Comment: That the Java and C++ implementation behaves similarly is also a strong indicator for branch prediction being at the root since the chip is the same

Answer (score 11):

I think this can indeed be explained by branch misprediction.

Consider, for example, LIMIT=11, and `sortB`. On first iteration of the outer loop, it will very quickly stumble upon one of elements equal to 10. So it will have `a[j]=10`, and therefore definitely `a[j]` will be `>=a[next]`, as there are no elements that are greater than 10. Therefore, it will perform a swap, then do one step in `j` only to find that `a[j]=10` once again (the same swapped value). So once again it will be `a[j]>=a[next]`, and so one. Every comparison except several at the very beginning will be true. Similarly it will run on the next iterations of the outer loop.

Not the same for `sortA`. It will start roughly the same way, stumble upon `a[j]=10`, do some swaps in a similar manner, but only to a point when it finds `a[next]=10` too. Then the condition will be false, and no swap will be done. An so on: every time it stumbles on `a[next]=10`, the condition is false and no swaps are done. Therefore, this condition is true 10 times out of 11 (values of `a[next]` from 0 to 9), and false in 1 case out of 11. Nothing strange that branch prediction fails.

Answer (score 9):

Using the C++ code provided (time counting removed) with the `perf stat` command I got results that confirm the brach-miss theory.

With `Limit = 10`, BubbleSortB highly benefits from branch prediction (0.01% misses) but with `Limit = 50000` branch prediction fails even more (with 15.65% misses) than in BubbleSortA (12.69% and 12.76% misses respectively).

**BubbleSortA Limit=10:**

```
Performance counter stats for './bubbleA.out':

   46670.947364 task-clock                #    0.998 CPUs utilized          
             73 context-switches          #    0.000 M/sec                  
             28 CPU-migrations            #    0.000 M/sec                  
            379 page-faults               #    0.000 M/sec                  
117,298,787,242 cycles                    #    2.513 GHz                    
117,471,719,598 instructions              #    1.00  insns per cycle        
 25,104,504,912 branches                  #  537.904 M/sec                  
  3,185,376,029 branch-misses             #   12.69% of all branches        

   46.779031563 seconds time elapsed
```

**BubbleSortA Limit=50000:**

```
Performance counter stats for './bubbleA.out':

   46023.785539 task-clock                #    0.998 CPUs utilized          
             59 context-switches          #    0.000 M/sec                  
              8 CPU-migrations            #    0.000 M/sec                  
            379 page-faults               #    0.000 M/sec                  
118,261,821,200 cycles                    #    2.570 GHz                    
119,230,362,230 instructions              #    1.01  insns per cycle        
 25,089,204,844 branches                  #  545.136 M/sec                  
  3,200,514,556 branch-misses             #   12.76% of all branches        

   46.126274884 seconds time elapsed
```

**BubbleSortB Limit=10:**

```
Performance counter stats for './bubbleB.out':

   26091.323705 task-clock                #    0.998 CPUs utilized          
             28 context-switches          #    0.000 M/sec                  
              2 CPU-migrations            #    0.000 M/sec                  
            379 page-faults               #    0.000 M/sec                  
 64,822,368,062 cycles                    #    2.484 GHz                    
137,780,774,165 instructions              #    2.13  insns per cycle        
 25,052,329,633 branches                  #  960.179 M/sec                  
      3,019,138 branch-misses             #    0.01% of all branches        

   26.149447493 seconds time elapsed
```

**BubbleSortB Limit=50000:**

```
Performance counter stats for './bubbleB.out':

   51644.210268 task-clock                #    0.983 CPUs utilized          
          2,138 context-switches          #    0.000 M/sec                  
             69 CPU-migrations            #    0.000 M/sec                  
            378 page-faults               #    0.000 M/sec                  
144,600,738,759 cycles                    #    2.800 GHz                    
124,273,104,207 instructions              #    0.86  insns per cycle        
 25,104,320,436 branches                  #  486.101 M/sec                  
  3,929,572,460 branch-misses             #   15.65% of all branches        

   52.511233236 seconds time elapsed
```

Answer (score 3):

> **Edit 2:** This answer is probably wrong in most cases, lower when I say everything above is correct is still true, but the lower portion is not true for most processor architectures, see the comments. However, I will say that it's still *theoretically* possible there is some JVM on some OS/Architecture that does this, but that JVM is probably poorly implemented or it's a weird architecture. Also, this is theoretically possible in the sense that most conceivable things are theoretically possible, so I'd take the last portion with a grain of salt.

First, I am not sure about the C++, but I can talk some about the Java.

Here is some code,

```
public class Example {

    public static boolean less(final int a, final int b) {
        return a < b;
    }

    public static boolean lessOrEqual(final int a, final int b) {
        return a <= b;
    }
}
```

Running `javap -c` on it I get the bytecode

```
public class Example {
  public Example();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #8                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static boolean less(int, int);
    Code:
       0: iload_0
       1: iload_1
       2: if_icmpge     7
       5: iconst_1
       6: ireturn
       7: iconst_0
       8: ireturn

  public static boolean lessOrEqual(int, int);
    Code:
       0: iload_0
       1: iload_1
       2: if_icmpgt     7
       5: iconst_1
       6: ireturn
       7: iconst_0
       8: ireturn
}
```

You'll notice the only difference is `if_icmpge` (if compare greater/equal) versus `if_icmpgt` (if compare greater than).

Everything above is fact, the rest is my best guess as to how `if_icmpge` and `if_icmpgt` are handled based on a college course I took on assembly language. To get a better answer you should look up how your JVM handles these. My guess is that C++ also compiles down to a similar operation.

> Edit: Documentation on `if_i<cond>` is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.if_icmp_cond)

The way computers compare numbers is subtracting one from the other and checking if that number is 0 or not, so when doing `a < b` if subtracts `b` from `a` and sees if the result is less than 0 by checking the sign of the value (`b - a < 0`). To do `a <= b` though it has to do an additional step and subtract 1 (`b - a - 1 < 0`).

Normally this is a very miniscule difference, but this isn't *any* code, this is freaking bubble sort! O(n^2) is the average number of times we are doing this particular comparison because it's in the inner most loop.

Yes, it may have something to do with branch prediction I am not sure, I am not an expert on that, but I think this may also play a non-insignificant role.

Comment: I don't think you are correct about `<` being faster than `<=`.  Processor instructions are discretized; each instruction must take an integer number of clock cycles-- there's no "time saved" unless you can squeeze a whole clock out of it.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12135533

Comment: Note that I'm talking about native code only.  I suppose it's possible that a JVM implementation could perform that "optimization", but I'd guess that it would just use the native instructions rather than cook up its own solution.  But that's just a guess.

Comment: On what do you base your assertion that <= uses an extra step to subtract an extra 1? At the x86 level, for example, a `cmp` followed by a `jl` will take exactly the same amount of time, successful branch prediction permitting, as a `cmp` followed by a `jle`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135518/is-faster-than has more details.

Comment: @ClickRick The assembly I learned was for SPARC which used a reduced instruction set. Maybe it didn't have `jle`? Or maybe I heard this false assumption somewhere too. Not 100% sure where I got this now that I really consider it. I suppose theoretically though that how any particular OS's/Architecture's JVM interpreted it could make some difference, but I would now assume they all do this in a single cycle.

Comment: @CaptainMan According to http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~agupta/_projects/sparc_simulator/SPARC%20INSTRUCTION%20SET-1.htm the SPARC supports both `bl` and `ble` instructions, which is entirely unsurprising to me.

Comment: @Click I am utterly at a loss how I came to this then. Maybe I heard something like `for (int i = 0; i <= thing.size() - 1; i++)` had to do an extra operation when I was learning and over the years associated it with `<=` (the `- 1` doesn't help haha). I'll add an edit that my answer is wrong unless the JVM for some particular OS/Architecture is implemented oddly.