# Understanding gcc output for if (a>=3)

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86

[image]

I thought since condition is a >= 3, we should use `jl` (less).

But gcc used `jle` (less or equal).

It make no sense to me; why did the compiler do this?

Comment: The assembler code is comparing with `2` not the `3` in the C code. So it is `jle` not `jl`.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code and asm as text, not an image of text.

Comment: The jump is there to reach the else-part, so it is *not* the condition you wrote for the if-part.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 7):

You're getting mixed up by a transformation the compiler made on the way from the C source to the asm implementation.  gcc's output implements your function this way:

```
a = 5;
if (a<=2) goto ret0;
return 1;

ret0:
return 0;
```

It's all clunky and redundant because you compiled with `-O0`, so it stores `a` to memory and then reloads it, so you could modify it with a debugger if you set a breakpoint and still have the code "work".

See also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)

---

**Compilers generally prefer to reduce the magnitude of a comparison constant**, so it's more likely to fit in a sign-extended 8-bit immediate instead of needing a 32-bit immediate in the machine code.

We can get some nice compact code by writing a function that takes an arg, so it won't optimize away when we enable optimizations.

```
int cmp(int a) { 
    return a>=128;   // In C, a boolean converts to int as 0 or 1
}
```

[`gcc -O3` on Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'int+cmp(int+a)+%7B+%0A++++return+a%3E%3D128%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:31.841101117470707,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-Wall+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:32.802575596160864,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:34.82556554919597,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang500,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-Wall+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+5.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:3,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:%233,t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), targetting the x86-64 ABI (same as your code):

```
    xorl    %eax, %eax           # whole RAX = 0
    cmpl    $127, %edi
    setg    %al                  # al = (edi>127) : 1 : 0
    ret
```

So it transformed a `>=128` into a `>127` comparison.  This saves 3 bytes of machine code, because `cmp $127, %edi` can use the `cmp $imm8, r/m32` encoding ([`cmp r/m32, imm8` in Intel syntax in Intel's manual](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CMP.html)), but 128 would have to use `cmp $imm32, r/m32`.

BTW, comparisons and conditions make sense in Intel syntax, but are backwards in AT&T syntax.  For example,  `cmp edi, 127` / `jg` is taken if `edi > 127`.

But in AT&T syntax, it's `cmp $127, %edi`, so you have to mentally reverse the operands or think of a `>` instead of `<`

Answer (score 3):

The assembly code is comparing `a` to two, not three. That's why it uses `jle`. If `a` is less than or equal to two it logically follows that a IS NOT greater than or equal to 3, and therefore `0` should be returned.